# After installing Git on windows, I cannot check version or any commands using execution of other programs. What's wrong?

Tags: php, git

I installed Git version 2.6.2.windows.1. After installing, any other programs in *my PATH environment variable* will display a flash console whenever I check their versions.

For example, from current pointer, I run "`node -v`" or "`php --version`" (both node & php are in **PATH**), the result which I got is a new console just flashes.

I think the content of any commands above are displayed in that console.
And in main console which I run command to check just like below:

[image]

This thing causes so many problems for me .

I tried to setup debug on my ide - phpstorm. But it seems not to recognize php version. Because the result is displayed in a new console and that console will be disappeared most immediately.

So could anybody help me fix this?

Comment: Try uninstalling git, uncompressing https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit.7z.exe anywhere you want and open a git-bash.exe: see if that work better that way.

Comment: Hi @VonC, sorry for my late reply. I still meet that problem even though I tried uninstalling git and using portable git instead. Don't know what is happening to me ?!

Comment: Hi @VonC, maybe I installed cygwin before i install git. Cygwin overrided my cmd, am I right? :(
Don't know which cygwin package destroyed my terminal. I uninstalled cygwin, but this problem's still there. Could you help me fix this?

Comment: Sure. I have proposed a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

First, forget cygwin.
Then (for a Windows 64 bits), uncompress or install in path **without spaces and in lowercase** (so not the default `C:\Program Files\...`, but rather `C:\prgs\git` or `C:\prgs\php` for instance):

- [`php-7.0.1-Win32-VC14-x64.zip`](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-7.0.1-Win32-VC14-x64.zip)
- [`PortableGit-2.6.4-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.4.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.4-64-bit.7z.exe)
- [`node-v4.2.3-x64.msi`](https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.3/node-v4.2.3-x64.msi) (it is an installer, see "[How to Install Node.js® and NPM on Windows](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows)", but use a simpler path like `C:\prgs\node`)
- [phpstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/#tabs_1=windows-version) (you already have it in your case)

In a brand new CMD session, type:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\system32
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\prgs\php\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\prgs\git\nodejs
cd c:\path\to\phpstorm
PhpStorm.exe
```

In that new PhpStorm editor, configure the path of php, and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Hi @VonC, my issue is still there. Sorry for my late reply. I think I should re-install the windows :(